# How to pass this param in URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, webserver, exchangewebservices, webservice-client

**How to pass this param in URL**
*http://localhost:8080/serviceweb/agent*

````
    @Path("/agent/{code}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object Response(
            @PathParam("code") String code,
            @QueryParam("user") String user,
            @QueryParam("password") String password) { ```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.